# find and replace in javascript globally

Tags: javascript

```
function function1() {
    var str = "prob[0].Key = '101';prob[10].Key = '101';prob[newIloop].Key = '101';prob[0].Key = '101'";
    str = str.replace(/prob\[[^\]]*?\]/g, 'prob[__]');
    alert(str);
}
```

I want to result output like

```
prob[ind(0)].Key = '101'; etc....
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is `prob[0] = 11; prob[1] = 12; prob[5] = 54;` a string?

Comment: replace [0] with [ind(0)] if [0] has prefixed with "prob".
I mean any prob[x] i.e. prob[0], prob[i] occurred, then it replace with prob[ind(x)].

Comment: So... this is JavaScript source code, and you want a search and replace regular expression for your **editor** to modify it? Otherwise, if you expect a regular expression in JavaScript, I fail to see how it should be applied to this example.

Comment: at its best this is off-topic

Comment: str = str.replace(/prob\[[^\]]*?\]/g, 'prob[__]');
I have tried this one. its works fine, but i cant get [x] value for replacing.

Comment: So it is a string... it's confusing to post the content of a string which is also valid source code of the language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
'...'.replace(/prob\[(\d+)\]/g, 'prob[ind($1)]');
```

`$1` is replaced with the text captured with your first capturing group.

Comment: I have one more question. if you dont mind.
 var key = "name";
                var str = "prob.name.name[0].Key = '101';prob.name[10].Key = '101';prob.name[newIloop].Key = '101';prob.name$$$[0].Key = '101'";
                //str = str.replace(/prob.name\[[^\]]*?\]/g, 'prob.name[__]');
                str = str.replace(/prob.+<<key>>  \[(\d+)\]/g, 'prob.name[ind($1)]');
                alert(str);

Here I can't add key varible into the replace string..

Comment: Post that as a new question. I can't read code from a comment.

Comment: ` var key = "name"; 
                var str = "prob.name.name[0].Key = '101';prob.name[10].Key = '101';prob.name[newIloop].Key = '101';prob.name$$$[0].Key = '101'";
                //str = str.replace(/prob.name\[[^\]]*?\]/g, 'prob.name[__]');
                str = str.replace(/prob.+<<key>>  \[(\d+)\]/g, 'prob.name[ind($1)]'); 
                alert(str);`

Comment: @user1812171: Post a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068769/javascript-find-and-replace-with-variable-in-regular-expression